# How to use a certificate from a dongle in non-interactive scenarios

Tags: java, certificate, usb, dongle, safenet

When using a certificate from a dongle (for instance, SafeNet), the certificate is not available unless an interactive session (on a Windows server in my case) is open, finally meaning that the certificate cannot be used for server operations unless a real person has opened a session.

Is there any configuration that can be set up so that this scenario becomes possible ?

Implementation details : code that requires access to the token is written in Java and works perfectly fine in interactive sessions. When included in a service (more specifically a tomcat container), it does not detect the dongle.